# Output Error - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter in website, and i dont truly know how to use CodeIgniter, so i ask here.

I cant get username and password in output when i use CodeIgniter
I'm using `<?=$user->username?>` and `<?=$user->password?>` to get username and password in my mysqli database.
so this is my code that i dont know where the problem here is:

```
$username = "<?=$user->username?>";
$password = "<?=$user->password?>";
$debug = true;
```

i want to process the string to be

```
$username = "rezafahmi";
$password = "blablablabla";
```

and the output is

```
 "username":"rezafahmi","password":"blablablabla"
```

but the output is:

```
"username":"","password":""
```

so what the problem?

Thank you everyone for attention, sorry for my language, i dont know english language too much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have code you haven't shown us which is the PHP templating.  Maybe something that looks like this

```
"username":"<?= $username ?>","password":"<?= $password ?>"
```

If so, then in your code above, remove the `<?=` tags from within the strings (in fact, remove the `"` completely).

```
$username = $user->username;
$password = $user->password;
$debug = true;
```

When you used `<?=` inside strings, PHP treats them just like any other characters that can be found in strings.  `<?=` is only treated by PHP as a place to substitute an express if and only if the `<?=` is in the output/template and not in the executable code parts of the PHP file.

(With your code, do "View Source" in the browser and you might see that the value of username is in fact `<?=rezafahmi?>` which HTML treats as a non-displayable tag.)

Comment: yes its works, i just need remove `<?=` and `?>` string :D thanks you very much sir!